# Converting PDF to images of original size

Tags: image, pdf

I have a PDF file which is made of photographs of a book connected in a single PDF file. I'm trying to convert it back to single images in PNG format, every tool I tried asks me to set DPI which alters the size of resulting images, is there a way to get images of the exact same pixel size the original images were?

Comment: In general, no.  The PDF doesn't store the original image.  It stores them at whatever resolution the encoder uses, usually 300 DPI.  Have you tried the `pdfimages` tool?

Answer (score 0):

Most PDFs of books contain a single image per page and depending on the scanner these images can basically be in three different formats: JPEG, JPEG2000 or TIFF. JPEG2000 is rarely used, so your PDF probably contains JPEG and/or TIFF images.

The good thing about JPEG (and JPEG2000) images is that they can be embedded as-is into a PDF! So you can extract the images as they are stored in the PDF. With TIFF this is also sometimes possible (but I don't think always...).

As mentioned by Tim Roberts you should try using `pdfimages` or `hexapdf images` to view and extract the images stored in the PDF. This will give you the best result.